# Why is my public IPv6 address different from the one listed in linux

Tags: linux, networking, ip, ipv6, nat

Going to [whatismyip.com][1] on different devices inside my home network provides expected results, the same IPv4 address and different IPv6 addresses on each device. However, upon looking at the results from `ip addr` on my Linux machine, the IPv6 address listed as public by whatismyip does not match the global address from `ip a`. So I looked at my router's webpage where it lists another, different, IPv6 address which also doesn't match. From my understanding of IPv6 my IPv6 global address should be the one used to connect to the internet because NAT is unnecessary. If this is the case then why does my public IPv6 address differ from any of the addresses I can see?

`ip a` output:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp170s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether bc:09:1b:f3:db:80 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.5.190/24 brd 192.168.5.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp170s0
       valid_lft 596378sec preferred_lft 596378sec
    inet6 2600:380:a024:3474:547e:15a3:8b35:cc6f/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 4294960775sec preferred_lft 4294960775sec
    inet6 fe80::7eb0:86b7:1494:689e/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

From my understanding, the inet6 address starting with 2600 is the one I should be looking for as the other is link-local.

Comment: Interesting. I would also expect them to be the same. Do the upper 64 bits of the addresses match at least? If so, then maybe the ISP is performing some weird NAT shenanigans? If they don't match, then perhaps the browser is going through a VPN or proxy that is changing the path taken to reach whatismyip.com?

Comment: Yes the upper 64 bits match, I also thought it could be NAT, though I have no idea why they would use NAT with IPv6

Comment: Do you get the same results when using other websites to check (e.g. test-ipv6.com or elsewhere)? Does your router report _both_ of its addresses (for the WAN and LAN interfaces)?

Comment: So the result from test-ipv6 is different from whatismyip.com and whatismyipaddress.com, which are the same

Comment: Are you sure you are showing all the output from "ip -6 a". There must be an entry marked "scope global temporary dynamic", which should be used to connect to the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Since the prefix (top 64 bits as per your `ip a` output) is staying the same, my guess is that NAT is involved... somewhere. I'm just not sure where or why.

Specifically, I think that SNAT is being used to translate between the hosts' "internal" IPv6 addresses and different "external" IPv6 addresses somewhere along the path. E.g., a `MASQUERADE` entry in `ip6tables` on your host machine, or a SNAT setup on your router or somewhere within your ISP's infrastructure.

I'm not sure why this would be deployed -- the whole point of IPv6 is to obviate the need for things like NAT of any kind, be it SNAT or DNAT -- but it *does* seem like there is *some* support for the concept [in commercial products like FortiOS](https://docs.fortinet.com/document/fortigate/6.4.0/new-features/568227/support-for-ipv6-in-central-snat-table). Specifically, it mentions "Central SNAT" for IPv6 and seems to show IPv6 SNAT behaviour like what you're seeing (same upper 64 bits/prefix, but with different contents in the lower 64 bits):

```
(FG-traffic) # diagnose sniffer packet any icmp6 4
interfaces=[any]
filters=[icmp6]
3.602891 wan2 in 2000:10:1:100::41 -> 2000:172:16:200::55: icmp6: echo request seq 0
3.602942 wan1 out 2000:172:16:200::199 -> 2000:172:16:200::55: icmp6: echo request seq 0
3.603236 wan1 in 2000:172:16:200::55 -> 2000:172:16:200::199: icmp6: echo reply seq 0
3.603249 wan2 out 2000:172:16:200::55 -> 2000:10:1:100::41: icmp6: echo reply seq 0
4.602559 wan2 in 2000:10:1:100::41 -> 2000:172:16:200::55: icmp6: echo request seq 1
4.602575 wan1 out 2000:172:16:200::199 -> 2000:172:16:200::55: icmp6: echo request seq 1
4.602956 wan1 in 2000:172:16:200::55 -> 2000:172:16:200::199: icmp6: echo reply seq 1
4.602964 wan2 out 2000:172:16:200::55 -> 2000:10:1:100::41: icmp6: echo reply seq 1
^C
8 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Granted, I might be misinterpreting that sniffer traffic snippet. Perhaps it *isn't* showing IPv6 SNAT behaviour.

My only other guess would be that there is no IPv6-only path between your host and `whatismyip.com`, so `NAT64` and `NAT46` are involved somewhere in the circuit/path, and `whatismyip.com` is picking up a `NAT`ed address that way. However, my limited understanding of those technologies is that in that particular odd scenario, `whatismyip.com` would be getting an entirely different prefix from a separate network. E.g.,

`IPv6-host-A` -> NAT64 -> `IPv4-host-A` -> NAT46 -> `IPv6-host-A'` -> `IPv6-host-B`

In this scenario, `IPv6-host-A` has a totally different IPv6 address from `IPv6-host-A'`, and `IPv6-host-B` only sees the prime address, `IPv6-host-A'`.